# Merging frontend and backend for production

Tags: angularjs, apache, symfony, gulp

I have a web project, powered by Symfony2 for the RESTful API, and by AngularJS for the front. It seemed logical to divide the project in two subprojects : one for the backend, and the other one for the frontend. The frontend build system is made with Gulp.
What I am trying to do is configuring my web server, Apache2, so it would first try to match the request URL to the front-end files, and, if it didn't matched with any of those files, then pass to Symfony's front controller. How should I configure Apache2 in order to make this working ?

For the moment, I have put my two subprojects one next to the other in the file hierarchy, and configured Gulp to output compiled files to the `web/` folder of my Symfony project, but I don't find that solution very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .htaccess.
If you are using **$routeParams** then set 404 url for everything that don't match. 
Then write rule for this page with redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?404$
 RewriteRule .* index [R=301,L]
```

This is a sketch, but if You are using html5mode on false, then it may work.